# Why was this question reopened when it is clearly asking to identify more than one work?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing-questions

This question: [What are these classic 80's action movies?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/281408/what-are-these-classic-80s-action-movies) was closed as "Needs more focus" and then subsequently reopened.

This was surprising to me. It's demonstrably asking to identify more than one work. There are two answers, each identifying a completely different movie.

More complications arise when thinking of our story-id policy on duplicates. Would this question serve as a good dupe target for the movie Akira (the accepted answer)? And it can't be closed as a dupe of this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65222/child-goes-on-an-adventure-and-comes-back-with-a-black-rock-of-pure-evil/65227#65227), even though (one of) [the answer(s)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/281426) correctly identifies Time Bandits.

**I am curious. Why was this question reopened and why does it remain open?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Why was this question reopened[?]*

@lfurini's [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/281408/what-are-these-classic-80s-action-movies#comment776152_281408) is instructive as to his (and my) thinking.

> I'm voting to reopen this, as I think it does not contain a bunch of unrelated questions but rather asks to identify several sci-fi scenes from a definite source, not unlike [other](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/171218/40711) [character](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/220860/40711) [identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/253083/40711) [questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/267719/40711) that were well received (having screenshots would definitely improve the question, though)

Asking it as a series of separate questions would be less *messy*, but so would all of the other examples given in his comment.

---

> *"It's demonstrably asking to identify more than one work."*

At the time of asking OP had no idea that these were two distinct properties.

Comment: "_At the time of asking OP had no idea that these were two distinct properties._" - this I did not know. Knowing that, the actions on the post make more sense to me

Comment: @Fez - You're not wrong. They should have posted one question for each ID. Had they turned out to all be from the same film, we could have duped them to each other.